# java - issue using enumeration to get data from a hashtable

Tags: java, enums, hashtable, java-7

I haven't touched Java for a while and am just going through some old code trying to update it to Java 7; I'm just trying to get back up to speed. Could anyone possibly offer some advice on the following code as Enumeration appears to be deprecated now.

```
private Hashtable table = new Hashtable();
```

...

```
Enumeration enum = this.table.keys();
while (enum.hasMoreElements()) {
   string test = (String) enum.nextElement();
  testMethod(test);
}
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated; thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
private Map<String, String> table = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : table.entrySet()) {
    testMethod(entry.getKey());
}
for (String key : table.keySet()) {
    testMethod(key);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) instead of the HashTable (which is obsolete) and a [for-each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html). It is also good practice to use [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) in order to avoid casts:

```
//assumes the keys are int and values String
private Map<Integer, String> table = new HashMap<> ();

for (String element : table.values()) {
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Enumeration is not deprecated, its just been *genericized*. For both your hash table and enumeration you should be specifying concrete types. For example:

```
Hashtable<Integer, String> table = new Hashtable<Integer, String>
Enumeration<Integer> enum = this.table.keys();
```

In this case your keys are Integers and your values are Strings. The new generics provide stronger type safety for your code. You should definitely also consider using some of the newer collection classes (like [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), for example).

Comment: @assylias - yes, though I prefer the term legacy. Modern Java code really should never use those legacy collection types.

Answer (score 1):

Use the keySet() method instead of keys() and then you can use an Iterator on the returned Set, or an enhanced for loop that does the iteration code for you, like this;

```
private Map<String> table = new HashMap<String>();
for (String key: table.keySet())
  testMethod(key);
```

You don't have to switch the implementation of the table to HashMap, but it is advised unless you can't. You can still use keySet() on the Hashtable if needed